# How can a name be displayed in the default calling screen for a certain number when the number was not saved in contact list?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

In the incoming default UI, I want to be able to display the caller's name when a specific number is not saved in the contact list.
eg:- The name is printed when we receive a call from Amazon, even if the phone number is not saved.

*note:- I don't want my own dialer app, nor do I want to display a popup like a True caller.*

How can we achieve that?

Comment: What makes you think it can be achieved at all? It would require modifying an existing app, that's only possible if the app explicitly made functionality to do so.

Comment: I am having that requirement that's why I asked.
and what do you mean by modification existing app?
I am talking about screen of default phone dialer application.

can you just explain. :)